# How can I use pandas to iteratively search for the value of column A in column B until there is no further match?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

As an example, I have the following table:

| Group Name | Parent Group ID | Group ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| All Foods |  | 3 |
| Italian Foods | 3 | 1 |
| Pasta | 1 | 2 |
| Spaghetti | 2 | 4 |

The group IDs are assigned arbitrarily. The table represents a series of nested groups. You can see that 'Spaghetti' has a Parent Group ID of 2, which corresponds to the Group ID of 'Pasta'. In turn, 'Pasta' has a Parent Group ID of 1, indicating that its parent group is Italian Foods.

I would like to be able to iterate across each row, identify the Parent Group ID and then follow the Parent Group ID - Group ID chain to find the top-level Parent Group Name for that row's group. In the case of row 5, 'Spaghetti', I would like to find that 'All Foods' is its top-level Parent Group Name.

I have so far tried to user pandas' outer join function to no avail. Any advice would be really appreciated.

The flow I have envisioned is this:

1. add a column to the right of the table
2. iterate through each row
3. find groupID value
4. search for groupID value in parentID column
5. repeat until parentID value is empty
6. add final row's group name onto original row's appended column

Comment: Not a huge fan of using Pandas for this, since I don't see how this operation can be vectorized. Must you use Pandas? I think storing this in a tree structure would be much better.

Comment: Hi @BrokenBenchmark - no, Pandas is not necessary here, but my research for the answer always seems to return to the use of Pandas so I assumed it might be the easiest method. I will look further into a tree structure - many thanks